# Keep two inserted tables on the same page

Tags: tables, input

I have produced two tables that when ran from the same LaTeX file are positioned on the same page, one under the other. However, when the two tables are called upon by using `\input` they appear on two seperate pages.

Here is a MWE (with the pacakges used in my paper) that produces the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[authoryear, round]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape, longtable}
\newcommand\iid{i.i.d.}
\newcommand\pN{\mathcal{N}}

\begin{document}
\include{Results_Tables/tablea}
\include{Results_Tables/tableb}
\end{document}
```

Whereas using this amended MWE would produce the desired output, where both tables are within one tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[authoryear, round]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape, longtable}
\newcommand\iid{i.i.d.}
\newcommand\pN{\mathcal{N}}

\begin{document}
\include{Results_Tables/tablea_and_b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\include{...}` always put `{...}` on new page. Try to use `\input{...}`.

Comment: Fantastic! If you submit this as an answer @Zarko , I will gratefully accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro `\include{...}` always put `{...}` on new page. Instead it use `input{...}`.