# classicthesis: How do I remove the empty space after chapter title?

Tags: chapters, classicthesis

I have the following files:

**Thesis.tex**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\newcommand{\bflabel}{\aclabelfont}

\input{classicthesis-config}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\include{input}
\end{document}
```

**input.tex**

```
\blindtext
```

**classicthesis-config.tex**

```
... copied from the distribution ...
```

When I put `\chapter` before the `\include`, what I get is this:

[image]

Instead, when I move `\chapter{Introduction}` to `intput.tex`, I get this:

[image]

I wonder why this is the case.

Comment: That is not normal, your document is doing crazy things and we don't see it.

Comment: @Johannes_B In that case I will provide an MWE, I thought this was normal.

Comment: Turns out the space occurs only when `\chapter{Introduction}`  is in the main file, not in the included file (see edited question).

Comment: `\include` makes a clearpage

Comment: `\include` always forces a new page.  the `\chapter` line should be in the `\include`d file.  (this must have been asked before.  i'll go looking.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton ^^^^ [Keep two inserted tables on the same page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258877)

Comment: another duplicate: [Page break with \include](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18110/579)

Comment: Funnily, if I have an input file which contains only the statemen `\bibliography{mybib}{}`, it does not matter where the `\chapter{References}` is located, it always puts the bibliography on a separate page. Why is that?